# C++ no suitable conversion function from to exists

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the function `membername` to return the strings `staffmember` and `usermember` is this not possible using the data type strings? If not, is there another data type I can use?

```
    string membername()
    {
        if (member == 1)
        {
            string studentmember;
            cout << "Enter Student Member Name (possible names: Tom, Max, Ben): ";
            cin >> studentmember;
            return studentmember;
        }

        if (member == 2)
        {
            string staffmember;
            cout << "Enter Staff Member Name (possible names: Linda, Mary, Bob): ";
            cin >> staffmember;
            return staffmember;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Enter a valid number" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `string membername();` why the semicolon?

Comment: Also (unrelated but should mention this), all paths of your function should return something, should `member` be 1 or 2, your program will run on *undefined behavior*... Even `return "";` suffices if you don't need anything there but *don't* leave any holes which don't return a value in a non-void function

Comment: `string membername();`  ends the declaration of the function `membername` because of the errant `;` the code block following the semicolon { if ...} is not allowed in the global scope (not part of the function declaration and not seen as an implementation of the function) causing the errors.

Comment: BTW, your function returns a string, a name.  The caller has no idea if the name is a staff member or a student.  You could reduce this to `"Enter name".`.  Or consider changing your design and put the input method inside the appropriate class or structure.

Comment: Also consider using named constants, such as `const int STAFF_MEMBER = 2; const int STUDENT_MEMBER = 1;` instead of the numbers.  Your code will be more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
struct Person
{
    int id;  // Every person has an ID.
    std::string name;  // Every person has a name.

    // Every Person has a function to input their name,
    //    implemented (specialized) by the child.
    virtual void    get_name() = 0;
};

struct Student : public Person // A student is-a person
{
    void get_name()
    {
        std::cout << "Enter Student's name:";
        std::getline(std::cin, name);
    }
};

struct Staff : public Person // A staff member is-a person
{
    void get_name()
    {
        std::cout << "Enter Staff's name:";
        std::getline(std::cin, name);
    }
};
```

The student and staff objects have different `get_name` methods.

You can treat them generically as a person:

```
Person * p1 = new Student;
Person * p2 = new Staff;
p1->get_name(); // Get the name of the person, using appropriate prompt.
p2->get_name(); // Uses the Staff::get_name() function.
```

For a template version, you would have to use a method (or member) for the person type.

```
template <typename College_Person>
void get_name(College_Person& cp)
{
   const std::string person_type_name = cp.get_type_name();
   std::cout << "Enter " << person_type_name << " name: ";
   std::getline(std::cin, cp.name);
}
```

Or

```
template <typename College_Person>
void get_name(College_Person& cp)
{
    std::cout << "Enter "
              << cp.person_type_name
              << " name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, cp.name);
}
```